# Xamarin Forms missing projects

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I create a Xamarin forms project in visual studio (Enterprise 2019 16.11.27), it only 3 projects. All only 'how to' recourses the form creation should generate 4 projects.

When creating a 'FirstApp" project I get the following;

- FirstApp.Android
- FirstApp.IOS
- FirstApp.UWP

But is missing the FirstApp project, what I'm doing wrong or has a update occurred that now means this needs to manually created?

Answer (score 0):

I've also had this problem before.

You can try to repair your visual studio. For how to repair visual studio,please check document: [Repair Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).

If the problem persist, please try to uninstall your Visual Studio and then reinstall it again.

Comment: Repairing and reinstalling didn't resolve the issue. :(

Comment: You can report this problem in the Visual studio directly. Please see this document about [Report a problem with the Visual Studio product or installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-report-a-problem-with-visual-studio?view=vs-2022).